# Creat clusters using long and lat

Tags: qgis

I have about 4000 stores all across the country. Based upon the long/lat distance and business level, I wish to create about 200 clusters who can manage 15-25 stores each. I wish to find out how to go about this to find these 200 clusters. Is it possible to do this? If any suggestions, please suggest how to go about it.